# Add new root base definition for Pinia

Tags: vue.js, quasar, pinia

I have added `axios` to my Pinia store in a Quasar's boot file

```js
export default boot(async ({ app, store, ssrContext, router }) => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
    paramsSerializer: serializeParameters,
  });

  store.use(() => ({ api }));
  }
});
```

Now I would like to augment my Pinia store to be able to use `this.api` inside my `actions`. I have tried using all examples in the [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#typing-plugins)

```
import 'pinia'

declare module 'pinia' {
  export interface PiniaCustomProperties {
    api: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

export const useGroupStore = defineStore('groups', {
  actions: {
    getGroups() {
       this.api <-- it is giving me undefined (or any)
    }
  }
})
```

How can I augment my store to be able to use `this.api` inside my actions?

Comment: This works in a standalone `create-vue` project with TypeScript, but it doesn't in Quasar for some reason. I would post a discussion in Quasar's or Pinia's repo.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that `useGroupStore()` is in some way called BEFORE the code with `store.use(() => ({ api }));`.

Note that whatever you add to the store this way will only be available in store instances created after that. If `useGroupStore()` comes first, `api` will not be visible inside.

You may want to look into the order of your boot files and maybe set breakpoints in these methods to see which one runs first.